# Как вывести сообщение при успешной отправке данных в sql?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть вот такой php код:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "test";
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['data']); //I've added $conn inside mysqli_real_escape_string expected 1st param
$moscow_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['moscow_1']);
$moscow_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['moscow_2']);
$mo_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['mo_1']);
$mo_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['mo_2']);
$total = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['total']);
$point = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['point']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO grafics (data, moscow_1, moscow_2, mo_1, mo_2, total, point) VALUES ('$data', '$moscow_1', '$moscow_2', '$mo_1', '$mo_2', '$total', '$point')";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // I think this will add data in your database.

$result = 'empty';
if (!$conn) { //I change this from mysql_query($sql)
    $result = 'Error: ' .mysqli_error();
} else {
   $result =  "Entry added successfully";
   mysqli_close($conn);
} echo '<p>'.$result.'</p>';
```

Есть вот такой js код:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#save").on('click', function () {
            var data = $("#data").val();
            var moscow_1 = $("#moscow_1").val();
            var moscow_2 = $("#moscow_2").val();
            var mo_1 = $("#mo_1").val();
            var mo_2 = $("#mo_2").val();
            var total = $("#total").val();
            var point = $("#point").val();


            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "save_grafic_1.php",
                data: {
                    "data": data, "moscow_1": moscow_1, "moscow_2": moscow_2,
                    "mo_1": mo_1, "mo_2": mo_2, "total": total,
                    "point": point,
                },
            }).done(function (data) {
                var result = data;
                $("#message").show(3000).html(result).addClass('success').hide(5000);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

И такой html:

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

Буду благодарен! Спасибо!

Comment: а сейчас разве не показывает?

Comment: Проверьте на всякий случай верстку. Возможно просто по каким-то причинам у вас высота блока, в который вы выводите контент равна нулю или еще что-то в этом роде. Попробуйте сначала просто вывести контент без удаления с задержкой и поискать результат в HTML коде и проверить CSS настройки.

Comment: @Ипатьев, сейчас не показывает...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте привести код запроса в такой вид:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "save_grafic_1.php",
  data: {
      "data": data, "moscow_1": moscow_1, "moscow_2": moscow_2,
      "mo_1": mo_1, "mo_2": mo_2, "total": total,
      "point": point,
  },
  success: function (data) {
    $("#message").show().html(data).addClass('success');
  }
});
```